# how to makes my image in xml able to zoom?

Tags: android, xml, image, layout

i create an app with button that will redirect to this layout if
 clicked. but the problem is, i cannot zoom the images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
<Linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ImageView
     android:src="@drawable/keutamaandua"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'zoom the images' ? Do you just need to set the image size in your layout ? Or do you need some dynamic scaling based on user gesture ?

Comment: ok here is the situation, i have a small text on my images, so i want to make an option for the user who want to get a clear view on the text in images.for an example, user can zoom in and out, or if you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense to have a `wrap_content` parent with a `match_parent` child because you don't really give any constraint.

You should probably use `match_parent` for the root layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
<Linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageViews do not have zoom capabilities by default. You can either find a [library that provides a widget that does](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) or do a simple tap to zoom [like in this example](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html).